# Is there any way to restrict how many item returned by CodeCentral Web Service

Tags: delphi, service

I am building web client for CodeCentral web service from CodeGear web site.

I need to restrict number of items return by Search operation of CodeGear web service, say it, 10 per page. This way I can minimize loading of my web page.

I just don't know how to do it. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

Sorry, I don't know the answer off hand.

I would suggest you contact John Kaster of CodeGear.  He would know all the ins and outs of that.  I haven't seen him posting here.  Usually the email is [first initial][last name]@codegear.com.  You might also try posting in the [Developer Network / CodeCentral forum](https://forums.codegear.com/forum.jspa?forumID=8) which I imagine John and his team will be monitoring.

Answer (score 0):

You're right. The search form on the CodeCentral page lists the maximum number of entries as an option (the "Show" option), but does not allow you to select the option. And trying various obvious parameter values doesn't work.

I haven't tried it, but what might help you is if you research the CodeCentral Expert, which is a package to help search the CodeCentral website from within Delphi and C++ Builder:  http://dn.codegear.com/article/23023

The package seems to be quite old, since comments on that page date from 2000, so there's no guarantee that it will work with the new site. However, checking through archive.org, it appears that the CodeCentral search page has remained the same for quite a number of years, and the search page, and even the missing "Show" option, has not changed over that time.

Even if the package doesn't work, maybe the package will give you the correct parameters you need for the calls to their search.

Otherwise, you'll have to send an email as previously answered.